# How do I get a list of viewers to a google document

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-activity-api

I am looking to replicate the gsuite capability of viewer trends over a document.
I can't find in the activity-api how to get a list of viewers, it returns only modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, neither the Activity API nor the Drive API has information about who **viewed a particular file at a particular time**. It's present function is like an audit trail, which shows what **changes** were done on the file and who did that change.

**Reference:**

[Drive Activity resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/driveactivity)

[Class Action Detail](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actiondetail#ActionDetail)

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is any alternative way to get this info?

Comment: Sadly, I have also checked this, and the only thing I found was in the Drive API. There, you can see the "viewedByMeTime". The only way to get this would be to use a service account and act as each user who has access to the document to get this for each one. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource